# Refrences break console app from running on other machines

Tags: c#, reference, console-application

I've made a console application which inserts data into a MySql backend, and reads the serial number from a hard disk

To do this i had to add `References` to MySql.Data and to System.Managment.

The way im running it is by copying the `Debug` directory from visual studio (i think this is the problem) and running the `.exe` file on the other machine.
When i run the application on another machine the stack trace error is:

```
PhDD >C:\Users\User\File\Indexer\WMI\Debug
Your key: 634685018347902535133
Exception getting SMART Object: reference not set to an instance of an object.
Exception in main thread:    at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeExcept
ion()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.get_Item(Int32 index)
   at WMITest.Menu.Run() in C:\Users\fps700\Music\WMITest\Menu.cs:line 49
Updated HDD Stats at28/03/2012 18:46:57
```

Am i correct in thinking this problem is because of the referencing ? 
I've checked the methods by recompiling the same code on the other machine and it works, when the references are added through VS.

Can anyone guide me on how to resolve this issue ?
Cheers for reading.

P.S. i tried adding reference paths (by right clicking on the project, selecting options and then choosing Reference Paths and adding the two dll files)

Line 49
`bool conversion = int.TryParse(smartData[1].ToString(), out temp);`

After adding a fake int value just to make sure conversion isnt the error the new stack trace error is:

```
PhDD >C:\Users\bborisov\Dropbox\Indexer\WMI\Debug
Your key: 634685018347902535133
Exception getting SMART Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Exception in main thread:    at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeExcept
ion()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.get_Item(Int32 index)
   at WMITest.Menu.Run() in C:\Users\fps700\Music\WMITest\Menu.cs:line 53
Updated HDD Stats at28/03/2012 19:00:24
```

line 53:

```
DBHandler.insertData(smartData[0].Trim(),
                            3, smartData[2], file.getKey());
```

Comment: Do you copy also MySql.Data.dll?. If you don't set the property CopyLocal = true, you don't have that file copied automatically in your debug directory

Comment: What does line 49 look like? Can any of the parameters be null due to the environment change not picking up something coded against on the developers machine?

Comment: so instead of referencing it i should copy it into the solution ?

Comment: @OmegaMan just removed the line where the conversion is occurring and now a new error is spawned

Comment: According to your edit, smartData doesn't have that number of items. And yes you have to copy the dll to the destination, reference is only to make it work at desing time, but when you run you need to know what to run (references are not added to the main project)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put code in to check validity of error situations which may be happening on the client pc but not the development one. You can handle the errors by either throwing an exception or handling it *gracefully* in a better way.

Here is the code which checks for error situations

```
if (smartData == null)
   throw new Exception("Smart data is null; aborting");

if (smartData.Any() == false)
   throw new Exception("Smart data instance is valid but has no elements; aborting");

bool conversion = int.TryParse(smartData[1].ToString(), out temp);
```

Comment: id rather by catching the errors than crashing the program :) but thank you anyway, your guide to including dll's helped. Upvoted.